# Why html element lose border-radius while dragging?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop, border-radius

Why did the element lose border-radius while I dragging them?
Seems element will cut the the background to fill four corners [lose radius](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Wbd.png)

item css class:

```
.list_item_pic {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-radius: 3vh;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: all ease 0.3s;
}
```

container css class:

```
.playlist_display_area {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: 60vh;
  padding: 0 10px;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 28vh);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 28vh);
  /* grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(28vh, auto));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(28vh, auto)); */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  display: grid;
}
```

React jsx code:

```
     <div className="playlist_display_area">
            {playLists?.map((playlist) => {
              const songs = playlist.songs;
              let listBg = songs[songs.length - 1]?.AlbmPic;
              listBg = listBg || this.trackBoxBgArr[getRandomInt(0, 5)];
              return (
                <div
                  key={playlist.listId}
                  className={`list_item_pic ${playlist.boxSize}`}
                  onContextMenu={(e) =>
                    this.onContextMenu(e, playlist, playLists)
                  }
                  draggable="true"
                  onDragStart={() => this.handleDragStart(playlist.listId)}
                  onDrop={(e) => this.ondrop(e, playlist.listId)}
                  onDragOver={(e) => this.handleDragover(e)}
                  style={{ backgroundImage: listBg }}
                >
                  <div className="list_inside_label">{playlist.name}</div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
```

[without pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIVYI.jpg)

Comment: this happens because you are setting the radius to the div but the image inside as the background overlaps the corners as soon as you drag. Try it with text only and see id the same happens.

Comment: @SalmanMalik same

Comment: Strange, can you share jsfiddle so I can take a better look at that?

Answer (score -1):

I assume that in this line

```
className={`list_item_pic ${playlist.boxSize}`}
```

the property `playlist.boxSize` refers to a class for which the border radius gets overridden.

If you want to prevent this from happening, just change the order of the classes:

```
className={`${playlist.boxSize} list_item_pic`}
```

Comment: size {
    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row: span 1;
    width: 28vh;
    height: 28vh;
}
this is size class